# Raspberry pi 4 not booting

Tags: pi-4

how do i fix raspberry pi 4 saying cant open sd card.
The green light is blinking 4 times fast then after about 5 seconds it starts flashing at a lower brightness forever...

Comment: Have ya' tried replacing the SD card?

Comment: or boot from a USB drive

Comment: yes, but the same thing for usb or sd card